# SQL Server in memory temp table disk usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've activated in-memory tables on my databases and use it only for table variables. However I notice that the disk space used by the in memory folder keeps growing and growing. I was wondering if there was a way to delete those files as there should be no persisted data in them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll get better answers over at [dba.se]

Comment: Ah didn't know there was a separate forum. Can I move the question or do I just repost ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be exactly the same except that the fix seems to be only for 2016.  I've found this though https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3147012/fix-large-disk-checkpoint-usage-occurs-for-an-in-memory-optimized-file . I've enabled the trace flag to see if it has any impact.

Comment: So you've enabled In-Memory on every database? Each database will have at least 2GB in in-mem files even if they are empty (see [this post by Michael Swart](http://michaeljswart.com/2017/11/postponing-our-use-of-in-memory-oltp/). My recommendation to him was to have a central stored procedure in one database that used table variables / TVPs instead of having that code in every database.

Comment: Not every database, 8 out of around 60 db. Current space taken by in-memory is 20 GB, so I guess according to the post you referenced, what I'm observing is normal behavior ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this post by Michael Swart](http://michaeljswart.com/2017/11/postponing-our-use-of-in-memory-oltp/) (provided by Aaron Bertrand), this seems to be the normal behavior of Hekaton.